# Some iOS constraints not working in Xcode 8 (after conversion to Swift 3)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, xcode8

I have quite a lot of views that are created with storyboards.  Everything except 2 items in the views are not working correctly and it has to do with the constraints.  It is almost like the constraints simply are not working or something.

When I am in the storyboard mode and change the constant value on the constraints, then 'update frames' nothing happens.  It doesn't shift around like it typically does when constraints change.

This is inside a table cell.  I have a view that is .5 thick that I want to stick to the bottom, and then I want it to extend to the trailing edge and to the leading.  When I set any of these constraints then press 'update frames', nothing happens.

The other control I'm having an issue with is a TextView.  It seems to have no height when in the application so again, something is going on with the constraints.  This looks to be the same thing happening in this case too.

I have tried recreating the view in Xcode 8 (just this one view that I'm having issues with inside my storyboard) and I get the same weird behavior.  I also tried saving it as Xcode 7.x mode as suggested in another thread, and I've also tried setting viewNeedsLayout in the code.  Neither of those are working.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you talking about when you add the constraints but they are not in their expected position so the constraint lines turn orange so you `Update Frames` and then they reposition?

Comment: I've seen some inconsistency with updating frames in Xcode 8 IB. When you run your storyboards do your views appear correctly?

Comment: When I run the storyboards, all views are appearing correctly except for these 2 issues I'm seeing.  The one storyboard with the textview that is not showing is pretty complex and everything else is working fine, including changing constraints in the code to make stuff slide up/down.  @Callam and yes I am talking about when you update constraint constants then select `Update Frames` from the small dropdown to make them update in the storyboard to the right positions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've now figured out issues for both of my issues.

1. It was a view that was 0.5 height but it did not have a constraint to be at that height.  I added a constraint, updated frames, and it updated to be correct as I would expect.

No clue how something like this could be fine in Xcode 7 then in Xcode 8 it works.  Apple really doesn't make developing easy huh.

2.
The textview I was using had a height constraint set to `<= 107`.  Well I changed it to `= 107` and now it works fine.  = actually works for me too since I'm changing the constant dynamically in the code anyways.  However, again, I still have no clue why this would work fine in Xcode 7 and not Xcode 8.

Answer (score 1):

I see this issue here too. As a workaround:

- Drag the affected view to a slightly other position (in Storyboard).
  Now the (->) shows up to signal the current position does not match the constraints:

[image]

- Click the (->)and choose "fix misplacements":

[image]

Comment: Where does this ! show up and where do I select fix misplacements from?